# How to compare 2 Date fields in Parse Cloud?

Tags: parse-platform

In a cloud function like the following, I am having problems comparing dates:

```
Parse.Cloud.define(“myCloudFunction”, function(request, response)
  {
    var query = new Parse.Query(“MyClass”);
    query.find
    ({
      success: function(resultList) {
        var today = new Date();

        for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; ++i) {
          if (resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)>resultList[i].get(“dateFieldTwo”)) {
            // Do something!!
          } else {
            // Do some other thing!!
            if (resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)>today) doOneMoreThing();
          }
        }

        response.success(resultList);
      },
      error: function() {
        response.error("Things have gone wrong.”);
      }
    });
  });
```

The lines :

```
if (resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)>resultList[i].get(“dateFieldTwo”))
if (resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)>today) doOneMoreThing();
```

are not working.

What is the syntax I am supposed to use in this context, to compare the two fields dateFieldOne and dateFieldTwo of type Date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Moment library](http://momentjs.com/docs/) is your friend here:

```
var moment = require('moment');
Parse.Cloud.define("myCloudFunction", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(“MyClass”);
  query.find
  ({
    success: function(resultList) {
      var today = new moment();

    for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; ++i) {
      var dateFieldOne = moment(resultList[i].get("datefieldOne"));
      var dateFieldTwo = moment(resultList[i].get("dateFieldTwo"));
      if (dateFieldOne.isAfter(dateFieldTwo)) {
        // Do something!!
      } else {
        // Do some other thing!!
        if (dateFieldOne.isAfter(today)) doOneMoreThing();
      }
    }
    // ...etc...
```

With Moment you can also query for the level of granularity you need, e.g.:

```
var today = moment();
var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days');
// assuming today is 3pm on 2014-07-09
moment("2014-07-09T20:00:00").isBefore(today); // false (8pm is not before 3pm)
moment("2014-07-09T10:00:00").isBefore(today); // true (10am is before 3pm)
moment("2014-07-09T10:00:00").isBefore(today, 'day'); // false (ignoring time, they are equal)
moment("2014-07-09T10:00:00").isBefore(tomorrow, 'day'); // true
moment("2014-07-09T20:00:00").isBefore(tomorrow, 'day'); // true
```

UPDATE: Note that `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` are only available after version `2.0` and Parse.com is using `1.7`. If you want to have access to these methods, you can download [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment) and place it in your `/cloud` directory.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I still have to figure out how to use this in Parse.
Even though I included :
var moment = require('moment');
in my code. I does work and I get an error :
Error: TypeError: Object Tue Jul 08 2014 15:56:01 GMT+0000 (UTC) has no method 'isAfter'

Comment: Since I have never used Cloud Modules, I may well be doing something wrong.

Comment: Is this:
var itemDate = moment(resultList[i].get("createdAt"));
supposed to work?

Comment: I have experimented unsuccessfully at this point. Obviously I am missing something basic.

Comment: Perhaps post an update to your question with your updated code? The `itemDate` line should work and give you a `moment` instance you can call methods like `isAfter()` on. Use lots of `console.log()` lines to see what is happening in code when debugging things like this.

Comment: Do I need to download or install something before the "moment module" can work?

Comment: No, it is one of the built in Cloud Modules described in the documentation. You just need the `require` line.

Comment: Thanks for you tips, but ... it still doesn't ... :) .. I made another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643412/trouble-using-the-moment-module

Comment: The thing now works after uploading the new version of moment.js.
By the way I have placed some console.log() in my code, but I must not be using it the right way because it displays nothing that I can see.

Comment: Console logs will show up in the Parse.com Dashboard, and also if you use the command line tool `parse log`.

Answer (score 1):

For this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; ++i) {
          if (resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)>resultList[i].get(“dateFieldTwo”)) {
            // Do something!!
          } else {
            // Do some other thing!!
            if (resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)>today) doOneMoreThing();
          }
        }
```

First convert it to unix timestamps and then compare them directly.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; ++i) {
              if (new Date(resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)).getTime()>new Date(resultList[i].get(“dateFieldTwo”)).getTime()) {
                // Do something!!
              } else {
                // Do some other thing!!
                if (new Date(resultList[i].get(“dateFieldOne”)).getTime()>today) doOneMoreThing();
              }
            }
```