# Parse Clouod Code Check If Date Is Today

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform

In my app i want a feature where the user can update their status but i want them to only be able to update it once every 24 hours. Basically i want to take the updatedAt field from parse and check if the change was today in Cloud Code.

I am not very familiar with javascript but her's what i've tried:
https://www.parse.com/questions/compare-date-and-createdat-to-figure-out-the-difference-in-days
[How to compare 2 Date fields in Parse Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630244/how-to-compare-2-date-fields-in-parse-cloud)

I couldn't get to a solution that would basically tell me (beforeSave) if the date is today and allow the user to save/update the field if it isn't.

An example of what i want is WhatsApp that only allowed changing the last seen status on/off once every 24 hours. Also Viber has this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Parse.com supports [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var updatedAt = ... ; // Get updatedAt value of your object
var now = moment();

if (now.diff(updatedAt, 'hours') >= 24) {
    // Last update was more than 24 hours ago
}
```

Comment: Can i do the same with NSDate? Pass NSDate to cloud code and compare it the same way?

Comment: Yes you can, Parse will convert the date for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I've used console log to check what the dates are and i am getting these : I2015-11-30T10:42:26.880Z]User Can't Post
I2015-11-30T10:42:26.881Z]2015-12-01T11:12:28.804Z
I2015-11-30T10:42:26.882Z]{"_d":"2015-11-30T10:42:26.877Z","_isUTC":false,"_a":null,"_lang":false} Even though the date is past 24 hours it still wont let the user post. Am i missing something?